# Wildfly 10 Can I set -Dspring.profiles.active in standalone.conf.bat?

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-10

Edit: I've tried adding `set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dspring.profiles.active=test"` inside standalone.conf.bat and this hasn't worked. It's as if it's being ignored.

---

Is it possible to set `-Dspring.profiles.active=test`like one might if calling

`java -Dspring.profiles.active=test -jar build/libs/weather-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

as a line in standalone.conf.bat? If not, what is the reason?

I've tried this (as well as in domain.conf.bat and appclient.conf.bat) and it seems to be completely ignored (I killed the java process and restarted the wildfly service to have the war redeployed). This is running on Windows 10.

Edit: it works perfectly fine when doing it from IntelliJ and running it in debug. I just want to be able to reproduce this on wildfly.
[image]

Comment: Are you using a standalone server and Windows? If so then adding that to the `JAVA_OPTS` should work.

Comment: I've added set `"JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dspring.profiles.active=test"` and it doesn't work. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"? How are you launching the server?

Comment: It's a standalone server on a machine running Windows Server 2012. By "doesn't work", I mean that when I specify `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` in standalone.conf.bat/standalone.bat (either or both), it shows-up in server.log under "VM arguments", yet the program, which is supposed to save a file to a folder named after the environment (i.e. "test"), it consistently saves to "dev" (the default env).

I've set the arg in standalone.bat for my local, win10 implementation, and it works like a charm.

Comment: If you see it in the `VM arguments` that means it's being passed to the VM so there must be a different issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem and it relates to specific changes to other .bat files made by other people who worked on this project within the "standalone" directory. There was some strange interference with how %JAVA_OPTS% was being set (and overwritten). Even though server.log logged (multiple times that `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` was set, it wasn't "sticking".

I resolved this by doing a dive into all the places the VM args were messed with in the .bats in `standalone`, using recursive file search in Notepad++. **The takeaway for anyone else** is that, if running on windows, you should be able to set `-Dspring.profiles.active=test` (or whatever your arg is) in `standalone.conf` (and nowhere else), and that should be sufficient to carry-over into the wildfly java.exe process.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Yes it's ideal to put changes in the `standalone.conf(.bat|.ps1)` and not edit the script directly.

Comment: I meant to say that, I'll edit to reflect that. Thanks.